# Retaining fragment after returining from activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have couple of fragments that is maintained by an activity. The app starts from the 'Home' fragment and when I go to 'Fragment A' and then go to a Settings activity and press back from from the Settings activity, 'Fragment A' is replaced by the 'Home' fragment. How do i retain the state of 'Fragment A' and keep the drawer open when returning from the 'Settings' activity?

For clarification, I want to return to the Fragment from where I launched an activity, in this case the settings activity, and not go back to the 'Home' fragment. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Here's my code for the drawer:

```
   if (id == R.id.fragOne) {
        fragment1 = new FragmentOne();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager1 = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager1.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, fragment1, "frag1")
                .commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.fragTwo) {
        fragment6 = new fragmentTwo();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager2 = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager2.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, fragment2, "frag2")
                .commit();
    } else if(id == R.id.helpDrawer){
        Intent drawerHelp = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Help.class);
        startActivity(drawerHelp);

    }
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer != null) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
    return true;
```

Comment: How are you moving back to Fragment From Activity ?

Comment: I'm pressing the back button from the activity to go back to the fragment. In my main activity, I'm overriding the back button to see if the drawer is open like so..                                                               @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer != null) {
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }
    }

Comment: Have you tried `supportFinishAfterTransition();` ??

Comment: Yes, I tried it in the block where I launch the help activity but when I press the back button from help activity, the app exits with no fragment to go back to. I will keep try different solutions. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

try adding finish() when back button is pressed in the settings activity. When we call one activity from other activity, the caller activity's instance state is saved so you fragment will be saved in stack and then called activity will be called so if you wish to go back then just finish the first activity and the caller activity's instance state will be called and you will get the same fragment from which you had called the settings activity.
So add this code in SettingsActivity.

```
@Override
onBackPressed{finish();}
```

this will solve your fragment issue.i am not sure about the drawer staying open.